# Jest unit test - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I'm trying to set up unit testing in Vue using Jest. However, I'm getting this error:

```
● Test suite failed to run
...
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

 >1 | import editUser from '@/components/forms/editUser.vue';
    | ^
  2 | import TestComponent from '@/pages/user/UserMyProfile.vue';
  3 | import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
  4 | import { expect } from 'chai';
  5 | import 'jest';
```

My Jest configuration in `package.json`looks like this:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "ts",
        "json",
        "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "modulePaths": [
        "<rootDir"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
        "node_modules",
        "src"
    ],
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/no-babel"
},
```

I have tried countless examples from other questions, but I can't seem to solve the issue.

Edit: For the record, I'm using TypeScript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is some of the (node_) modules you're using need to be transpiled and some don't. So you'll need to play with this syntax until you find the ones which need to be ignored:

```
"jest": {
  // what you already have...
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(a-module"
      + "|another-module"
      + "|yet-another-module"
      + ")/)",
  ]
}
```

... where `a-module`, `another-module` and `yet-another-module` are the modules you want ignored.
If you look closely at the error, you'll typically find the name of the module causing it. However, if you can't figure it out, try with every single module imported in `editUser.vue` has and then remove them one by one until you find the minimal amount of modules to be ignored.

Comment: After googling for many days and trying all other solutions, nothing else worked, except for this. Why is this not included in `ts-jest` documentation?

Comment: Just to be more specific: this approach is a double ignore for transpiling TypeScript npm dependencies in the node_modules directory. Like "ignore everything but ..." 
By default, jest seems to assume every npm package imported is just plain JavaScript and doesn't need to be transformed. Which saves a lot of time, of course.

Comment: In additioon to the answer, here is the official Jest [docs link](https://archive.jestjs.io/docs/en/24.x/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring) for `transformIgnorePatterns` Jest config option. And this is [the usage example](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization).